# Login to website with POST request using Python

Tags: python, http, post, networking, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from this website: https://encompass.com/account. I have to login then grab the data. However, I am having trouble finding the POST parameters to send the username and password by inspecting the network changes using developer tools in chrome.

I am using Python to do all this and I cannot seem to figure out to how to send username and password parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a json body in a POST request, you can do the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://encompass.com/account' # or whatever the endpoint is
credentials = {'user': 'user', 'password': 'password'}

response = requests.post(url, json = credentials)
```

If you need, you can also send headers, as explained [here](https://pynative.com/python-post-json-using-requests-library/)